# Exec inside a running container

Tags: bash, shell, docker, bin

I have created a running docker container with

```
docker run -v host_directory:remote_directory -it image_name /bin/bash
```

and right after creating it I can start running on it say specifically the ffc command. Then I do my stuff and close docker.

Next day I can see that my container is still running (as expected) and to run on it I do

```
docker exec -it container_name /bash
```

and I go inside my container but this time can not run ffc command, i get an error message saying "unknown command".

Anyone knows what is going on?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: yeah. `/bash` does not exist. try `/bin/bash`

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Aserre, I did docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash still ffc comment not found

Comment: What is ffc? 
docker exec -ti 686d5e43522c3 /bin/bash works!

Comment: ffc is Fenics Form Compiler. UFL is part of the FEniCS Project and is usually used in combination with other components from this project to compute solutions to partial differential equations. The form compiler FFC uses UFL as its end-user interface, producing implementations of the UFC interface as output.

Comment: I can only get to work this ffc compiler right after creating the container but not later when I do docker exec -it container_name /bin/bash

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here:

To be able to run the ffc command I was mentioning I needed to exec as a fenics user hence should do

```
docker exec -ti -u fenics <container name> /bin/bash -l
```